# How to pass $(this) to selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a jquery click handler which toggles one of list elements:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

With it I can change element I clicked expanding and collapsing it.

But what if I want only one element to be expanded and previously expanded element to close when I click to another one?

I want to do this passing both `$(this)` (clicked `li`) and `li.expanded` to jQuery selector for `toggleClass('expanded')`.

Something like (but this does not work):

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $(this, 'ul li.expanded').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:**
I need this function to work even if no elements was expanded before (on page start) and to be able to collapse previously expanded element when i click on it.

it **does not work** correctly if use (does not expand first item):

```
$('li.expanded', this).toggleClass('expanded');
```

but works fine with:

```
$('li.expanded').toggleClass('expanded');
$(this).toggleClass('expanded');
```

Answer (score 4):

Just changed the position of arguments passed to selector. The jquery selector accepts second parameter `context`. where you can pass the current context `this`:

```
$('ul li.expanded',this).toggleClass('expanded');
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
$(this).find('ul li.expanded').toggleClass('expanded');
```

**Full Snippet:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
  $('ul li.expanded').not($(this).find('ul li.expanded')).removeClass('expanded'); 
  $('ul li.expanded',this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: I think that this will only toggle class expanded for the clicked element, but it won't remove this class from the previous .expanded element

Answer (score 1):

**ToggleClass not working in your context**. its collapse all li's Use addClass and removeClass instead of

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $('ul li.expanded').removeClass('expanded'); // remove class expanded
    $(this).addClass('expanded'); // add class current li
});
```

Comment: So is this not possible to do this with one method?

Comment: @s.webbandit - you only told in your question "But what if I want only one element to be expanded and previously expanded element to close when I click to another one?"

Answer (score 1):

You can remove class 'expanded' from all `li` elements and add it to the clicked one:

This code

```
$('ul li.expanded',this).toggleClass('expanded');
```

does not work in this case

**WORKING DEMO**

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
  $('ul li').removeClass('expanded');
  $(this).addClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
li.expanded { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="expanded">test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
  <li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap!

```
$('ul li.expanded', this).toggleClass('expanded');
```

This is your code. The contextual `this` should come next!

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $('ul li.expanded', this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded'); //Add class to current li
    $('ul li.expanded').not(this).toggleClass('expanded'); //Toggle class from other li's
});
```